# Hero Passion Pro - Choke Issues

Tags: engine, motorcycle, carburetor, hero-honda, choke

I have a Hero Passion Pro Motorcycle.  It does not get started when the choke is on.  It does start when the choke is turned off?

The engine produces a disturbing noise and smoke goes out when the choke is on when it's been started for the first time. Once it is off then wont get start when choke is on

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean that when the engine is cold, it requires the choke, but then if you stop and try to restart, then you have to turn off the choke.

This is by design.

The choke is a tool to allow a cold engine to run by enriching the fuel/air mix through restricting (or choking) the air supply - once the engine is warmed up, this is not needed any more. When you stop the engine, and try to restart again before it has cooled down, using the choke forces the wrong fuel/air mix so it won't start.

Usually, using the choke on a warmed up engine just makes the engine run inefficiently (with lots of smoke) so there is something not quite tuned right on your bike.